# HTML5's !doctype is messing up my styles

Tags: html, styles, doctype

I'm currently working on some simple gallery, that should show thumbnails of a fixed size of 148px.

When I specify `<!doctype html>` at the very beginning of the file it messes up my style so that it looks like on this picture.

[image: How it should look]

Without this line (I guess the browser is working in HTML4 mode then) it looks correct:

[image: Hot it actually looks]

Take a look at the file by yourself: http://ablage.stabentheiner.de/2013-08-10_gallery.html

New file version: http://ablage.stabentheiner.de/2013-08-10_gallery2.html same file with different doctype: http://ablage.stabentheiner.de/2013-08-10_gallery2_html4.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Gallerie</title>
<base target="Hauptframe">
<style>
body {
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
    background-image:url(../background.gif);
}
table {
    border:none;
    border-spacing:0;
}
img {
    border:none;
}
A:hover {
    color: #FF0000; 
    font-weight: bold
}
.imagefloat {
    border: medium solid #FFF;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.nowrap {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.nowrapline2 {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.nowrapline3 {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.error {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F00;
}
.caption_cell {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 148px;
    height: 80px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="imagefloat">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/148x148" width="148" height="148" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="caption_cell">
            <td>

            <p class="nowrap">Title</p><p class="nowrap nowrapline2">Subtitle</p><p class="nowrap nowrapline3">Copyright</p>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="imagefloat">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/148x148" width="148" height="148" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="caption_cell">
            <td>

            <p class="nowrap">Title</p><p class="nowrap nowrapline2">Subtitle</p>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: The only difference I see between the images is a small overflow (like 5 pixels), and your page shows something different. What should we be looking at?

Comment: What browser are you experiencing this in?

Comment: I was testing this on Webkit-based browsers (latest Chrome and Safari 6 in detail). I added some placeholder for the images (seems that not all browsers generate a placeholder square when <img src="" is set to nothing ;)

Comment: You say, "When I specify ..." the doctype. Does that mean you don't have any at first? In that case, you are in quirks mode and using the broken box model. A doctype is required of all new web pages. The doctype is the very first thing to go on a page and you never, ever change it. Keep that in there and adjust your styles that way.

Comment: It's not called HTML4 mode, it's called "quirks mode". There are a number of differences between standards mode and quirks mode, and it varies between browsers, which is one reason you want to avoid quirks mode at all costs. Providing a doctype is the way to avoid quirks mode. I pasted your code into jsFiddle.com to try to see it in action, but it doesn't look much like your images, so I guess there's something missing. Can you create a working demo that shows the problem? It'll make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: It's the same when I explicitly set it to `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` which is something not-HTML5

Comment: It's the same when I explicitly set it to `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple enough. Images by default are handled as inline objects. For inline rendering, a minimum vertical clearance between rows is generally required and this is added by the browser for better readability. To remove this additional clearance try applying 'display: block' to these images.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, your problem here's simple: you aren't using valid HTML5. The first thing you should always check is that your code [validates as well-formed HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://ablage.stabentheiner.de/2013-08-10_gallery.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), which yours doesn't. After that, check your CSS too; but just be aware that if the problem is that your site displays more nicely in HTML4 mode than HTML5 mode, then that's not a bug, that means that you've done something wrong writing your code.

Your first step here is to fix all of the glitches which the W3C validator has pointed out; if that doesn't fix the problem, then take another look at your CSS.

Comment: I got rid of the errors and the validation page says my page is valid now: http://ablage.stabentheiner.de/2013-08-10_gallery2.html However the "4px too high"-issue is still there.

Comment: You can fix this by giving the <a> tag the following styles: {display: block; margin-bottom: -5px;}

That feels a little bit like a hack to me, but it'll resolve your issue. Hopefully someone else can give you a better idea of what's causing this, because as far as I can tell there's nothing that should directly cause this effect.